# how to hide create and edit button of form and tree view of lot/serial number for stock user in odoo10

Tags: odoo-10

I want to create and edit the lot/serial numbers only for admin and stock manager not for user.

```
<record id = "view_stock_production_lot_tree_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name ="name">Stock Production Lot Inherit</field>
    <field name ="model">stock.production.lot</field>
    <field name ="inherit_id" ref ="stock.view_production_lot_tree"/>
    <field name ="groups_id" eval = "[(4,ref('stock.group_stock_user'))]"/>
    <field name ="arch" type = "xml">
       <xpath expr ="//tree" position = "attributes">
          <attribute name ="options">{'no_create_edit': True, 'no_create':True}</attribute>
          <attribute name ="groups">stock.group_stock_user</attribute>
       </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

but it does not work!!

Comment: You set user rights. So they can't edit and create this lot and serial number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
<attribute name ="groups">!stock.group_stock_user,stock.group_stock_manager</attribute>
```

or set groups specifically to `stock.group_stock_manager` only

```
<attribute name ="groups">stock.group_stock_manager</attribute>
```